# How would you interpret "incapacitate" for a spell?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I want to take a Cat as Mentor Spirit, and the disadvantage is unclear for me:

> Cat magicians toy with their prey. Unless you succeed in a Charisma + Willpower (3) Test at the start of combat, you cannot make an attack that *incapacitates* your target. If you take any Physical damage, all this playing around stops.

Does this limitation mean I can not use combat spells at all, or I can not use high Force?
How could I know what incapacitates a Troll?
Or does this mean leaving the target alive to be able to play with it later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incapacitate):

> in·ca·pac·i·tate transitive verb \ˌin-kə-ˈpa-sə-ˌtāt\
>
> : to make (someone or something) unable to work, move, or function in
>   the usual way

I would interpret this (in the spirit of "toy with their prey") that you *do not want* to make an attack that you *expect* to kill, paralyze or knock out the target. So, no sleep spells, nothing that's typically a one-hit kill, etc. And don't try to find loopholes, that would just be bad roleplaying. Your character does that because it's *fun* and they can't resist doing it.

But note the last sentence:

> If you take any Physical damage, all this playing around stops.

So the restriction really only applies to surprise attacks and uneven fights.

Comment: So basically anything is ok that I can reasonably expect to leave the enemy standing?

Comment: @András, well, "moving" would be more appropriate, but yes, that's the idea.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Can't really agree with uneven fight part. The cat still wants to play after taking a Stunbolt/Tazer to the head? That needs to be addressed.

Comment: @Jeor Mattan: You're saying that the restriction to Physical damage doesn't fit the idea well? Could be...